# ComplexPhraseQueryParser

Tags: spring, hibernate, search, hibernate-search

I would like to implement for my website a fuzzy phrase search using Hibernate Search. I've read from some people that ComplexPhraseQueryParser is ok for this.

But the thing is that I have some missunderstandings or issues related to it.

So for instance let's consider a test title like this (I have a lot of this and I need to let users search whatever they like):

"Do you know how to be in shape?"

If someone will type
"do you cnow how to be in shape?"  my ComplexPhraseQueryParser will not find anyting. But if I put a "~" character after the misspeled word like "cnow~" it will work and return a result.

**What is the reason of this? Doesn't ComplexPhraseQueryParser support such situations?**

I would like to make my search deal with few misspelled words and return results (similar to google search).

```
ComplexPhraseQueryParser quizTitlePhraseQuery = new ComplexPhraseQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "title", new StandardAnalyzer(
                        Version.LUCENE_30)) ;
quizTitlePhraseQuery.setPhraseSlop(100);
                quizTitlePhraseQuery.setDefaultOperator(Operator.AND);
                quizTitlePhraseQuery.setFuzzyMinSim(0.1f);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am wondering the same thing.

Comment: ~ indicates the word to be searched as fuzzy

Comment: Can you let me know what analyzers are you using on title filed? I am trying the same thing, but not getting any results if I have multiple words in query. Only single 'exact' match is returned if any. appending ~ is not returning any results for single/multiple words